# How to insert image into database

Tags: php, html

How to insert image using PDO method?

I got these error messages:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\testform.php on line 21
>
> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): Error reading result set's header in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\testform.php on line 21

But when I upload smaller size image, it can stored into database, but the image name is not the image name.
My image name is "asdas"
but when it store into database, it become like this "?

> PNG\r\n\Z\n\0\0\0\rIHDR\0\0|\0\08\0\0\0m?:\0\0\0sRGB\0???\0\0\0gAMA\0\0???a\0\0\0    pHYs\0\0?\0\0??o?d\0\0??IDATx^??`T??6?????????c??{?R??*?? ??-=???    Ih!??F??HO?&B?U??s??????\'????Z?Z??a2?

```
<form action="testform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="image" type="file">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload Picture!">

</form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=forms1;host=localhost', 'root', 'root',
            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));

        $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
        $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);

        if(substr($imageType,0,5)=="image")
        {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO files (name,image) VALUES (:name,:image)');
            $stmt->execute(array('name' => $imageData, 'image' => $imageType));
            echo "Image Uploaded";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Only images are allowed";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: why do you escape the inputs and then use a prepared statement?  Isn't that a little redundant?

Comment: You don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` with `PDO` nor do you need to escape strings when using parameter binding

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo. Use `'name' => $imageName` in your parameter array. I can only assume the `image` parameter is meant to store `$imageData` as well, not type

Comment: OP, if this isn't solved with the answer below, ping me and I'll vote to reopen. The question is clear and shows a prior attempt, so happy to do so.

Comment: So anyone know what is the proper way to upload an image and save it into database? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your name field to `$imageData` instead of `$imageName` when you execute the prepared statement. I believe you mean for it to be:

```
$stmt->execute(array('name'=>$imageName,'image'=>$imageData));
```

As an aside, saving images directly into a database is generally considered very bad form.

Also, the mysql_real_escape_string calls are not needed. Using a prepared statement takes care of the escaping for you.